# Spring - Facebook integration without storing connections

Tags: java, spring, facebook, spring-social

I've been trying to integrate my application with facebook for a very long time, but I can't find any good example how to do this without storing user connections. I know that there is project called spring-social and I can integrate it by implementing SocialConfigurer methods , but it requires UsersConnectionRepository, which is a bad idea.

I also don't want to redirect my requests since I already have facebook access id ( it's passed from other application ). I simply want to log in and create user in my db ( if didn't exist before )

How can I do this ?

Ideally I would like to have something like this :

facebookService.getUserDetails(facebookAccessId) 
facebookService.getPhotos(facebookAccessId, ... )

No sessions etc

Answer (score 0):

So you just want to create a new user in your DB if it does not exist right? And no open connection? Then you can use JPA (When you are working with Java)  or Entity-Framework (.NET).

In JPA you can work in combination with objectdb. http://www.objectdb.com/
It's as simple as it sounds. (You can handle all with JPQL (SQL for JPA))
When you are also working with Maven you can implement JPA & Objectdb with this code: http://m2.objectdb.com/

Comment: I want to add possibility to login to my application via facebook, download photos from facebook etc. But I don't want to keep user sessions

Comment: Just save the user access token with the user-id? And everytime you crawl or whatever you want to do you can read it?    For understanding what kind of application is it?